Using Solana Pay and additional backend logic to handle SaaS subscriptions?
I'm running a SaaS platform with tiered subscriptions (free, basic, and premium) currently using Stripe for payment processing. I'm looking to introduce Solana Pay as a second payment method, starting with one-time payments and eventually expanding to handle recurring subscriptions. My goal is to gradually phase out Stripe in favor of Solana Pay.
Current setup:

Stripe handling monthly, quarterly, and annual subscriptions
Tiered pricing with different credit allocations (e.g., 5k credits
for    basic, 20k for premium)
Monthly reset of subscription credits

Planned implementation phases:

Introduce Solana Pay for one-time payments alongside Stripe
subscriptions
Expand Solana Pay to handle recurring payments and full
subscription management
Eventually phase out Stripe

Has anyone ever done something like this?
Any insights, code snippets, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
